Problem adding onnxruntime python package to a yocto build
I'm trying to add the meta-st-x-linux-ai to my yocto build setup so that I can have the onnxruntime python package available on my linux, but I get the following errors :

Notice that all my layers are on the kirkstone branch and I'm correctly mentionning all the necessary layers that meta-st-x-linux-ai depends on.
